# Extracting variable number of token pairs from a string to a pair of arrays

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing

Here is the requirement.

I have a string with multiple entries of a particular format. Example below

```
string SourceString = "<parameter1(value1)><parameter2(value2)><parameter3(value3)>";
```

I want to get the ouput as below

```
string[] parameters = {"parameter1","parameter2","parameter3"};   
string[] values = {"value1","value2","value3"};
```

The above string is just an example with 3 pairs of parameter values. The string may have 40, 52, 75 - any number of entries (less than 100 in one string).
Like this I have multiple strings in an array. I want to do this operation for all the strings in the array.

Could any one please advice how to achieve this? I'm a novice in c#.
Is using regex a better solution or is there any other method? 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Has your example of sourceString been lost in formatting?

Comment: Why is param3 in a different format?

Comment: Is that difference in the value3 intentional or accidental?

Comment: I don´t understand your question. Are you trying to PRODUCE or WRITE c# code?

Comment: Hi nabuchodonossor, I have the source string given. I have to write a c# code to generate the string array outputs as shown. thank you.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor, He takes in a string in the SourceString format and needs to parse it into two seperate strings. One with the parameters and the other with the values.

Comment: Assuming your formatting is standard, could you not iterate over the string where each parameter starts immedidately after '<' and finishes before '('? Similar for values where start '(' and end ')' are static and easily used?

Comment: Yes, TheCapn, formatting is standard. Parameters always are between the starting < and the first (. Values are always between ( and ). The parameter value pair ends at > and immediately a new parameter/value pair starts <parameter(value)>. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't like RegEx's you could do something like this:

```
  class Program
  {

    static void Main()
    {

        string input = "<parameter1(value1)>< parameter2(value2)>";
        string[] Items = input.Replace("<", "").Split('>');

        List<string> parameters = new List<string>();
        List<string> values = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            if (item != "")
            {
                KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp = GetInnerItem(item);
                parameters.Add(kvp.Key);
                values.Add(kvp.Value);
            }
        }

        // if you really wanted your results in arrays
        //
        string[] parametersArray = parameters.ToArray();
        string[] valuesArray = values.ToArray();

    }


    public static KeyValuePair<string, string> GetInnerItem(string item)
    {
        //expects parameter1(value1)
        string[] s = item.Replace(")", "").Split('(');
        return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(s[0].Trim(), s[1].Trim());
    }
}
```

It might be a wee bit quicker than the RegEx method but certainly not as flexible.

Comment: Thanks much DD59. Got the output exactly as needed from your post. Thanks again!!!!

Comment: No probs, glad I could help :)

Comment: Is there a way to do the same in Java? I'm not sure about the methods to use in Java. For example - foreach does not exist in java. Not sur how to get the same result, with the same input string format.

Answer (score 1):

You could use RegEx class in combination with an expression to parse the string and generate these arrays by looping through MatchCollections.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx

This does it:

```
string[] parameters = null;
string[] values = null;
// string SourceString = "<parameter1(value1)><parameter2(value2)><parameter3(value3)>";
string SourceString = @"<QUEUE(C2.BRH.ARB_INVPUSH01)><CHANNEL(C2.MONITORING_CHANNEL)><QMGR(C2.MASTER_NA‌​ME.TRACKER)>";
// string regExpression = @"<([^\(]+)[\(]([\w]+)";
string regExpression = @"<([^\(]+)[\(]([^\)]+)";
Regex r = new Regex(regExpression);

MatchCollection collection = r.Matches(SourceString);
parameters = new string[collection.Count];
values = new string[collection.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
{
    Match m = collection[i];
    parameters[i] = m.Groups[1].Value;
    values[i] = m.Groups[2].Value;
}
```

Comment: hi mservidio, i tried using regex, but it worked only for one set of parameter/value. I have multiple entries in one string. so want to get the parameters to one array and values to another. parameter and value arrays will have equal length.

Comment: Hi mservidio, Thanks for your help and quick response. When I use the actual data, the value part is getting truncated when the first '.' character occurs. Actual data - string SourceString = "<QUEUE(C2.BRH.ARB_INVPUSH01)><CHANNEL(C2.MONITORING_CHANNEL)><QMGR(C2.MASTER_NAME.TRACKER)>"; in the values array, i'm getting only the C2 of the total value. Your effort is highly appreciated. Let me try on modifying the regex expression to get the complete value. Thanks again!!

Comment: Oh, well I based the expression off of your example data. The expression would need to be modified to support the varying characters that you're showing now.

Comment: Sorry if my initial post was not accurate. What I meant in my post was one parameter value pair is between < and >. Out of which, whatever is there in between the ( and ) is the value.

Comment: Ok, let me know if the updated expression works better for you. It parses the new input string you gave...

Comment: Exactly !!. Thanks to you too.. I now have two methods to achieve my goal. Really appreciate this forum. Very helpful and kind. I got down and moved out of a few forums as the members / moderaters were quite rude. I seem very friendly here. Thanks to all of you, dear experts.!!!